# Registering Android App for Google APIs

Tags: android

Up until recently I was able to register an app with Google's API console using a single SHA1 key. Previously, you needed one key for your debug version and another for your release version. Then I noticed that Google simplified this and only required a single key, the release key, that would work for both debug and release. Today I went to register a new app but discovered that it appears they have reverted to requiring a debug and release key. Is that true or does a single key still work for both debug and release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I noticed that Google simplified this and only required a single key, the release key, that would work for both debug and release.

You can associate several SHA1 fingerprint + package name pairs with the same Maps V2 API key. If you associate the SHA1 fingerprints for debug and release APK signing keys with the same Maps V2 API key, you can use that one Maps V2 API key on both debug and release builds.

> Today I went to register a new app but discovered that it appears they have reverted to requiring a debug and release key.

I see nothing in the Google APIs console that has changed. You can still associate several SHA1 fingerprint + package name pairs with the same Maps V2 API key.